# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1

Tags: android

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson mGson = builder.create();
spinnerData = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response, Item.class));
```

After executing this code, size of spinnerdata list is showing 0. my response is:

{"result":[{"item_code":"r2010","item_name":"rice"},{"item_code":"w2010","item_name":"wheat"},{"item_code":"p2010","item_name":"paddy"},{"item_code":"b2010","item_name":"bran"}]}

my code for item.java is:

```
package com.example.booking;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Item {
     @SerializedName("item_code")
     private String item_code;
     @SerializedName("item_name")
     private String item_name;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String item_code, String item_name) {
        this.item_code = item_code;
        this.item_name = item_name;
    }

    public void setCode(String item_code) {
        this.item_code = item_code;
    }

    public void setName(String item_name) {
        this.item_name = item_name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return this.item_code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.item_name;
    }
}
```

the error shows:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.booking, PID: 12452
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
        at com.example.booking.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:82)
        at com.example.booking.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:77)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5730)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689) 
        at com.example.booking.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:82) 
        at com.example.booking.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:77) 
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60) 
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30) 
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5730) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)

after appyling the changes

Comment: Hi Suneha Ghosh and welcome to stackoverflow! Please post the source code for the `Item` class.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your response carefully. Here, `result` is an object, not an array. There is an array inside the `result` object. So you need to parse the JSON into an object. Then you can get an array from the `result`. I have given a sample entity from your given response and the output-

You can use your given code but with a little change -

```
String response = "{\"result\":[{\"item_code\":\"r2010\",\"item_name\":\"rice\"}," +
                "{\"item_code\":\"w2010\",\"item_name\":\"wheat\"},{\"item_code\":\"p2010\"," +
                "\"item_name\":\"paddy\"},{\"item_code\":\"b2010\",\"item_name\":\"bran\"}]}";

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson mGson = builder.create();
        Item spinnerData = mGson.fromJson(response, Item.class);

        List<Result> list = spinnerData.getResult();
```

Here, `list` will be your actual result.

Your Entity Is not correct for your response. The code below is the actual entity of your given response JSON -

```
public class Item {
    @SerializedName("result")
    private List<Result> result;

    public List<Result> getResult() { return result; }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) { this.result = result; }
}

class Result {
    @SerializedName("item_code")
    private String itemCode;

    @SerializedName("item_name")
    private String itemName;

    public void setItemCode(String itemCode){ this.itemCode = itemCode; }

    public String getItemCode(){ return itemCode; }

    public void setItemName(String itemName){ this.itemName = itemName; }

    public String getItemName(){ return itemName; }
}
```

Comment: List<Item.Result> list = spinnerData.getResult(); this line shows cannot resolve symbol. if i do List<Result> list = spinnerData.getResult(); nothing is showing

Comment: the errors are resolved but the same problem arises.

Comment: Can you please check your response? Gson expected `{` at the first but getting `"`.  Please check and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: this is the response i am getting {"result":[{"item_code":"r2010","item_name":"rice"},{"item_code":"w2010","item_name":"wheat"},{"item_code":"p2010","item_name":"paddy"},{"item_code":"b2010","item_name":"bran"}]}

Comment: Are you using your own `Item` class? There may be en `{` missing during parsing the JSON. Because my classes and functions won't work in your project. Please recheck your `@SerializedName` for every attribute. Thanks...

Comment: Your `item` class is not right for the response. Please check out my given code.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to get hide of objects that the only attribute is a list without rewriting model classes (if not necessary)

```
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;


spinnerData = mGson.fromJson(new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("result").toString(), new TypeToken<Item>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: thanks.... but this shows cannot resolve TokenType. are there any librabries to be imported?

Comment: ops i meant TypeToken instead